# Get Webservice WSDL in different project within same solution

Tags: c#, web-services

I have a Web Service Project and a Web Site Project both within the same solution. I have a simple link on a web page within the Web Site Project that needs to point to a web services WSDL (example: Webservice.asmx?WSDL) within the Web Service Project. Is this possible?

Would I be better off using a hardcopy of the WSDL document and just putting that in my web site project?

Comment: so what am i missing... WHEN do you want the wsdl at compile time or at runtime?  It seems like you want it at compile time but i'm not really sure why.... if you want it at runtime it's just as simple hyperlink... so forgive me not getting it - but I don't 'get' your question...  could you clarify what you're trying to 'do'?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe so. You will need to have the webservice run, in either IIS, or through visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

Why not add a Web reference to the Webservice (Browse for "Web services in this solution") ?

That's what adding the reference does, basically... along with creation of the class mapping. Then you could always update references without having to worry about hard coded wsdl links.

Comment: I am not sure how or if this accomplishes what I want. Added the reference would allow me to access the web service, but what I need is to basically load the page WebService.asmx with the "?WSDL" Appended to it.